# How to fix JSON with python?

Tags: python, json

my JSON file looks something like this:

```
{
    "key": "test", "expiry": "test",
    "key": "eb467ff5-da95-47b5-b2d4-d5d6e9141a47", "expiry": "2022-12-13",
    "key": "17fd8fd1-b920-4e42-8e81-450757f9c79a", "expiry": "2022-12-13",
    "key": "91a969af-263f-46c1-a2f3-12e876403de6", "expiry": "2022-12-13",
}
```

I want it to remove the last "," so the JSON doesn't have any errors. How would I do this? The error is the last , in the file: https://prnt.sc/mNVxXWOVBAOS

How do I do this with loading the file then doing it so it instantly writes the fixed version to file?

I was trying to do

```
                    comma_index = x.rfind(',')
                    s_cleaned = x[:comma_index] + x[comma_index+1:]
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Why do you think that your code didn't work? It seemed to work for me.

Comment: _but it didn't work_ Saying "it didn't work" is not helpful.  Instead, say what it **actually did**.

Comment: It just didn't do anything

Comment: Did you rewrite the json file with the cleaned contents?

Comment: @quamrana can you write an answer that loads the .JSON, and replaces it with fixed version please?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't do anything

Comment: Sure it does. Your code creates the new string `s_cleaned` that has the last comma remove and `json.loads()` won't complain.

Comment: _Yes, but it didn't do anything_ It must have done SOMETHING.  Did the file actually get rewritten?  Did you check the modification timestamp?  Are you sure you're looking at the right file?

Comment: Regardless of how you fix this, make sure you try to address the fact that something is giving you invalid JSON in the first place. Fix the producer, file a bug report, etc. It should not be your responsibility to decode invalid JSON like this.

Comment: It's my code lol, tryna make it look good...

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine:

```py
import json

x = '''{
    "key": "test", "expiry": "test",
    "key": "eb467ff5-da95-47b5-b2d4-d5d6e9141a47", "expiry": "2022-12-13",
    "key": "17fd8fd1-b920-4e42-8e81-450757f9c79a", "expiry": "2022-12-13",
    "key": "91a969af-263f-46c1-a2f3-12e876403de6", "expiry": "2022-12-13",
}'''

comma_index = x.rfind(',')
s_cleaned = x[:comma_index] + x[comma_index+1:]
print(s_cleaned)

t = json.loads(s_cleaned)
print(t)
```

Output:

```
{
    "key": "test", "expiry": "test",
    "key": "eb467ff5-da95-47b5-b2d4-d5d6e9141a47", "expiry": "2022-12-13",
    "key": "17fd8fd1-b920-4e42-8e81-450757f9c79a", "expiry": "2022-12-13",
    "key": "91a969af-263f-46c1-a2f3-12e876403de6", "expiry": "2022-12-13"
}

{'key': '91a969af-263f-46c1-a2f3-12e876403de6', 'expiry': '2022-12-13'}
```

Comment: how would I make it so it updates the JSON with the updated output?

Comment: What is `updates the JSON`?

Comment: So it replaces the old JSON with the fixed output, with no , at the end

Comment: What? You mean: `x = s_cleaned`?

Comment: Yeah, with no , at the end. How would I do that?

Comment: So, `x = s_cleaned`?

Comment: Yes, x = s_cleaned

Comment: @chronic You said you rewrote the json file.  And yet here you are asking how to do that.  Color me confused.

Comment: I said what? No I said I need it to rewrite to the JSON with the fixed output, I said I tried but didn't work

Comment: @chronic I asked "Did you rewrite the json file with the cleaned contents?" and you replied "Yes"...

Comment: "Yes, but it didn't do anything" is what I responded with, I tried to rewrite but didn't work.

Comment: This is out of scope. Your question is about cleaning a string and not about reading and writing files.

Comment: @chronic You keep saying "it didn't work", which is not helpful.  What did the code ACTUALLY DO?  Did you get errors?